# How to know of what activity is returning

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 3 activities: A, B and C.

From A I got to B and from A I go to C.

```
A --- B
|
|
C
```

When I return to A from this two activities, I press the back button.

From A, how can I know what activity was in the stack? How can I know if was B or C?

**UPDATE** - - 
I want to know how to know what activity press onBackPress(); I do not use startActivity from B or C;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Android's request codes with startActivityForResult(). In Activity A, call B or C with different request codes. First, define the codes:

```
private static final int ACTIVITY_B_REQUEST = 100;
private static final int ACTIVITY_C_REQUEST = 200;
```

Then start actvities.

B:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_B_REQUEST);
```

and C:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_C_REQUEST);
```

Then, still in your ActivityA, override onActivityResult() and check which request code has returned when back button was pressed:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case ACTIVITY_B_REQUEST:
            //returned from ActivityB
            break;

        case ACTIVITY_C_REQUEST:
            //returned from ActivityC
            break;

        default:
            break;        
    }
}
```

No need to pass anything from B or C - it's already taken care of by Android.

Answer (score 2):

When starting activities A and C, use `startActivityForResult(...)` instead of the regular `startActivity(...)`. You can create static integer variables for ACTIVITY_ID, ACTIVITY_B, and ACTIVITY_C. When your user backs out of either B or C, call `setResult(...)` with the corresponding ID variable. For more information about this method, see the developer doc on Activities: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: I want to know how to know this when in B and C was pressed onBackPressed(). I dont used startActivity(), only onBackPressed().

Comment: In `onBackPressed(...)` call `setResult(...)`. Override `onActivityResult(...)` in activity A. Get the result there.

Answer (score 1):

Start Activity B & C  as startActivityForResult, use setResult method for sending data back From B/C and in A receive data as onActivityResult.

[How to pass data from 2nd activity to 1st activity when pressed back? - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292398/how-to-pass-data-from-2nd-activity-to-1st-activity-when-pressed-back-android)