# Android overriding onBackPressed() to send intent

Tags: android

I am trying to override onBackPressed() to send data to the previous screen in an intent like so;

```
    thisUserObj = (User) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("UserObj");


    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("UserObj", thisUserObj);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

but when the button is pressed the UserObj values is null, however this works from a onClickListener

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), MainMenuActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("UserObj", thisUserObj);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to pass data from 2nd activity to 1st activity when pressed back? - android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292398/how-to-pass-data-from-2nd-activity-to-1st-activity-when-pressed-back-android)

Comment: if you are starting a activity using :

1. firsrt screen---startActivityForResult()--->second screen---then only use setResult().

2. first screen---startActivityForResult()--->second screen ---just override onbackpresss() and use startActvitiy to navigate back to first screen and pass data in intent . It should work

Answer (score 5):

Its `startActivity(intent)`. To get result in `onActivityResult()`, it should be `startActivityForResult()`.

Answer (score 0):

in First activity

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 100;
....

Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("UserObj", thisUserObj);  
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE); 


// still in first activity 

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         // do your stuff here            

        }
    }
}
```

in your second activity in your case MainMenuActivity class

```
thisUserObj = (User) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("UserObj");

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("UserObj", thisUserObj);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

to override back pressed button

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) { //Back key pressed
       //Things to Do
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: onKeyDown dosent seem to be getting called when i press the back arrow

Comment: If you want back to first activity when you click on back button write Intent intent = new Intent (Second.this , First.class); StratActivity(intent); finish ();