# Android onItemLongClick adds position to the arrayList in different activity

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener, onitemlongclicklistener

I have got two activities.

**My goal is:** After longClick on any `ListView` position in *activity 2*, I want some `String` to be added to `ListView` in *activity 1*. From *activity 2* I'm going back to *activity 1* by pressing `back` button. Each `ListView` has got different `adapter`.

I tried with `Bundle` (put `extra`), but it makes app crash.

**Fragment of code from activity 1:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start_layout);


 mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

        addDrawerItems();
        setupDrawer();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

}

private void addDrawerItems() { //It adds text ect. to listView - It works so I cut out the rest of code
        ar.add("anything");
        ar.add(lv.try);

        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ar);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        });
    }
```

Simply adding like `ar.add("anything");` works. The `lv.try` contains by default text "First text". I tried to update this variable in *activity 2* `onItemLongClick` `fragment` of code:

```
mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //What to type here?

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Putting simply `try = "Second text";` will not update my try variable. I tried also with `Bundle` (`extras`) but without success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood the question. Anyway, have you tried to override onBackPressed?

In the second activity you create a boolean variabile and inizialize it as false, then change its value when you perform a long click:

```
mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
       @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            longClick = true;
            return false;
       }
   });
```

Remember, longClick has to be a class variable!

Outside onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivityName.this, FirstActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("longClick", longClick);
   finish();
   startActivity(setIntent);
}
```

And in the first Activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.getBooleanExtra("longClick", false)) {
    addDrawerItems(); 
}
```

Comment: I got an idea of how to do that. The complete solution can be found here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292398/how-to-pass-data-from-2nd-activity-to-1st-activity-when-pressed-back-android   The problem was that I didn't even know than I can pass something when "Back" button is being pressed! Thanks for the effort! :)

Answer (score 0):

What does add position mean ?

In my opinion add position means add one element to a structure (array, list, etc).

So basically what I mean is that you can have an array in your CustomApplicatioClass or even a Static array(someone probably would not agree with me) and onItemLongClick() add the element you want in the structure.

Then when you load the Activity with the ListView you can do your ListView stuff using the updated structure

hope it helps