# Null pointer exception on pressing favorites button in single item view activity

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I have a listview which opens a new single itemview activity when clucked on each list item . Inside the singleitemview activity i have a favorites button which adds the list item that opened the singleitemview activity to my favorites activity using sharedpreferences.. To pass the listitem clicked I use jackson library to convert respective listitem to json string and use putextra via intent into singleitemview activity . Then I convert back the json string to listitem object in singleitemview  and use it to add to favorites

But now when i click the favorite button in singleitemview the app crashes and after reopening the app the listutem is added to my favorites activity

Here is the code

**onitemclicklistener of my list activity**

```
    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {

                            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                            Product pro = productListAdapter.getItem(position);
    try
    {
        String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(pro);
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), SingleItemView.class);
        intent.putExtra("selected item", jsonInString);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (JsonProcessingException e)
    {//something went wrong
          } 



}
```

**singleitemview.java**

```
public class SingleItemView extends Activity
 {
ProductListAdapter padaptr;
SharedPreference sharedPreference;

List<Product> products = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.singleitem);
    sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
    padaptr = new ProductListAdapter(SingleItemView.this, products);



    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.singleitemButton1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            String jsonObj = extras.getString("selected item");
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            try
            {
                Product pro = mapper.readValue(jsonObj, Product.class);

                       //the fav image present on evry list item
                ImageView button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite);
                if (checkFavoriteItem(pro)) {

                    sharedPreference.removeFavorite(SingleItemView.this, pro);
                    button.setTag("no");
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_grey);
                    Toast.makeText(SingleItemView.this,
                                   SingleItemView.this.getResources().getString(R.string.remove_favr),
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    sharedPreference.addFavorite(SingleItemView.this, pro);
                    Toast.makeText(SingleItemView.this,
                                   SingleItemView.this.getResources().getString(R.string.add_favr),
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    button.setTag("yes");
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {};





        }



            private boolean checkFavoriteItem(Product checkProduct) {
                boolean check = false;
                List<Product> favorites = sharedPreference.getFavorites(getApplicationContext());
                if (favorites != null) {
                    for (Product product : favorites) {
                        if (product.equals(checkProduct)) {
                            check = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return check;
            }
    });
    }


}
```

**the line pointing nullpointer eception log cat is**

```
                        button.setTag("yes");
```

**singleitem.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#A25550"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Addcto fav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/singleitemButton1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/singleitemTextView1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**list item xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/product_list_item_bg"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/pdt_layout_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_pdt_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="6dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_pdt_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_pdt_name"
        android:padding="6dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_pdt_desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_pdt_price"
        android:padding="6dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgbtn_favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_pdt_desc"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/favorites" />
</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pdt_layout_item"
    android:background="@color/view_divider_color" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

**my logcat**

```
01-27 17:29:19.777 14852 14852 E   AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 17:29:19.777 14852 14852 E   AndroidRuntime java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 17:29:19.777 14852 14852 E   AndroidRuntime at com.mycompany.myapp.SingleItemView$100000000.onClick(SingleItemView.java:62)
01-27 17:29:19.777 14852 14852 E   AndroidRuntime at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4452)
01-27 17:29:19.777 14852 14852 E   AndroidRuntime at android.widget.Button.performClick(Button.java:148)
01-27 17:29:19.777 14852 14852 E   AndroidRuntime at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18428)
01-27 17:29:19.777 14852 14852 E   AndroidRuntime at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-27 17:29:19.777 14852 14852 E   AndroidRuntime at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-27 17:29:19.777 14852 14852 E   AndroidRuntime at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
01-27 17:29:19.777 14852 14852 E   AndroidRuntime at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
01-27 17:29:19.777 14852 14852 E   AndroidRuntime at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 17:29:19.777 14852 14852 E   AndroidRuntime at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-27 17:29:19.777 14852 14852 E   AndroidRuntime at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
01-27 17:29:19.777 14852 14852 E   AndroidRuntime at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
01-27 17:29:19.777 14852 14852 E   AndroidRuntime at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 17:29:20.316 17044 17044 D   AndroidRuntime Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
```

Comment: Is imagebutton in singleitem.xml file?

Comment: Does that imagebutton id exist in the xml file of the singleitemview activity? Because your error is in initialising the Button variable.

Comment: @PiyushGupta no it is in list item

Comment: For your list activity??

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal the image button exists in list item of list view not in single item view

Comment: @PiyushGupta the xml which shows each list item in listview

Comment: @PiyushGupta tes in that

Comment: Do you need to call new activity mandatory? Other wise access view on item click of listview

Comment: @user5524159 Can you tell me why you need to change a value in the listview when you are already in the `SingleItemView` Activity? Do you need to open a new activity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason:**
The reason you are getting this `NullPointerException` is that you are trying to access an id as `imgbtn_favorite` in the `singlelistitem.xml` where it does not exist. *You can access a variable only in the xml associated with the Activity class*.

**Solution**: I noticed that you were using that variable only to set the `Tag` and change `ImageResource`. You can't do this from another Activity. For this you can either

1. Store a global value in `SharedPreferences` and show the changed value when the `listview` opens again.
2. Or, if you *do not need* to open a new Activity, you can access the View in the ListView Activity itself.

EDIT:

3. You can also use `startActivityForResult` so that you send some values back to the ListView Activity **and then** make the changes in the variable. You can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292398/how-to-pass-data-from-2nd-activity-to-1st-activity-when-pressed-back-android/14292451#14292451) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

**First** of all in click event initializing view by `findViewById` is not a good approach. Initialize it outside of click event.

**Second** your `Button` is not initializing properly, that's why it's getting null.

Comment: Thanx very much for that advice So i initializeed the button outside click event but still the same problem . How shall i solve ir

Comment: can you post your singleitem.xml file? in that xml file is there any id exist as "imgbtn_favorite" ?

Comment: the image button exists in list item of list view not in single item view

Comment: my assumption is right. you can not initialize any view which does not exist in your activity. in "SingleItemView" activity you inflated "singleitem.xml" which does not contains your expected view. Thats why when he tries to find "imgbtn_favorite" in "SingleItemView" , it finds nothing. so you are getting null. Read some article about data passing between activity. it will help.

Comment: I came to android from ios developing can you texplain poease

Comment: so i have to pass it via intent in onitemclick same as i've did for the list item

Comment: that's huge things to explain everything. If you are new start from this : http://developer.android.com/training/index.html . search "start activity for result".

Comment: thnx for your advice , appreiate it

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
ImageView button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite);
```

By

```
ImageView button = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite);
```

Comment: Trid as you said but still the same prolem

Comment: posted the xml files

Comment: You are currently in singleitem view. So it will try to find the button in it while its in the listview layout. Thats why its null. You can't get the UI component of other activity in this.

Comment: You will have to check the shared preferences while populating the listview and set the tags there.!

Answer (score -1):

You need to move this line:

```
ImageView button = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite);
```

out of your try catch (place it just before this block).  You have not initialized in your else statement.