# Pass string from Activity B to Activity A

Tags: android

I have two activities, Activity A, and B. When user clicks on a topicTextView in the Activity A, it takes him to Activity B where user choses a Topic and pass selectedTopic to the Activity A.

I have implemented the following but app crashes first time when opens Activity A.

**Activity A**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  topicTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.topicTextView);
  // crashes in the following line
  String selectedTopic = getIntent().getExtras().getString("selectedTopic");
  if (selectedTopic != null && !selectedTopic.isEmpty()) {
   topicTextView.setText(selectedTopic);
  }
}
```

**Activity B**

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)   {
      Intent i = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class);
      i.putExtra("selectedTopic", topics[position].toString());
      startActivity(i);
   }
 });
}
```

Comment: so what is your problem

Comment: Please see my updated question

Comment: Put the complete code how you start your ActivityB from A

Comment: Show crash logs. also make sure calling setContentView with right layout in which `topicTextView ` is present

Comment: your intent must be null in activity A.....show Error log

Comment: Ether your intent is null or your `topicTextView` do not belong to `Activity A` layout file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before fetching value , check weather `Bundle` is having that value or not. Problem in your case is when you run for first time, `getIntent().getExtras().getString("selectedTopic");` will return `null`

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("selectedTopic"))
{
    String selectedTopic = getIntent().getExtras().getString("selectedTopic");
    if (selectedTopic != null && !selectedTopic.isEmpty()) {
      topicTextView.setText(selectedTopic);
    }
}
```

Another good way is to use `startActivityForResult()` and pass your value from activity B which you will get in `onActivityResult()` of activity A, check this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292398/how-to-pass-data-from-2nd-activity-to-1st-activity-when-pressed-back-android) question for this approach

Comment: I will mark your answer when sof allows me, I have upvoted. I have tested and works like a charm. Could you please also illustrate the other approach just in case as a reference if you don't mind.

Comment: @texas yes i have given link in updated answer, refer that for second approach

Answer (score 1):

It is coming null because the very first time you are coming to activity A, you do not have that string in the intent so put a check whether that string is there in the intent

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("selectedTopic")){
String selectedTopic = getIntent().getExtras().getString("selectedTopic");
  if (selectedTopic != null && !selectedTopic.isEmpty()) {
   topicTextView.setText(selectedTopic);
  }
}
```

Better is to use startActivityForResult() to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Change your code:

```
String selectedTopic = null;
if(getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().hasExtra("selectedTopic")){
 selectedTopic  = getIntent().getExtras().getString("selectedTopic");
}

if (selectedTopic != null && !selectedTopic.isEmpty()) {
   topicTextView.setText(selectedTopic);
}
```