# Have to press the back button twice to get to previous activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onbackpressed

I am simply trying to click back and navigate to my previous activity. My flow is this: I go to `news_feed activity` -> `Comments activity` -> `User Profile activity` -> `click back` (Go to `Comments activity`) -> `click back` (This does nothing for some reason) -> Click back (Go back to `news_feed activity`). I'm not sure why I have to click `back` twice when I try to go from `Comments activity` back to `news_feed` activity. If I go from `news_feed` activity -> `Comments` -> press back (Go to `news_feed activity`) this works perfectly. Here is my code:

news_feed.java:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
}
```

Comments.java:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    this.finish();
}
```

UserProfile.java:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(UserProfile.this, Comments.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("postId", postId);
    bundle.putString("posterUserId", posterUserId);
    bundle.putString("posterName", posterName);
    bundle.putString("postStatus", postStatus);
    bundle.putString("postTimeStamp", postTimeStamp);
    bundle.putString("postTitle", postTitle);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

I don't think navigating to these activities would change anything, but I can include the intents that I used to navigate to these activities also if necessary. Otherwise I just included the `onBackPressed` code that I had for these activities. Any ideas why this might cause a problem? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Don't call `finish()` in `onBackPressed()`

Comment: Why are you using onBackPressd in Comments activity, if you just need to finish it. I will finished when you press back without writing onBackPressCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `UserProfile` class, in `onBackPressed()` method, you are starting the `Comments` class again. Why do you have to do this?
What is happening is, you are starting a new Comments activity `onBackPressed()` of the USerProfile class, so there are two instances of Comments Activity. So you feel you are pressing back btn twice.

If you have to pass data back to `Comments` from `UserProfile` class, then make use of `setResult()` method.

This will be of help

[How to pass data from 2nd activity to 1st activity when pressed back? - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292398/how-to-pass-data-from-2nd-activity-to-1st-activity-when-pressed-back-android)

[Sending data back to the Main Activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920306/sending-data-back-to-the-main-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
private boolean clicked;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!clicked) { // if it was not clicked before, change the value of clicked to true and do nothing directly return, if clicked again, then it will be finish the activity.
        clicked=true;
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

And if you are going to use the time, then you can do like this:

```
private long lastClicked;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastClicked  < 1000) { // within one second
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    lastClicked = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I you want to send back the result to previous activity the start activity by using

```
startActivityForResult()
```

insead of

```
startActivity()
```

and don't override

```
onBackPressed()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onBackPressed() {


        if (this.lastBackPressTime < System.currentTimeMillis() - 2000) {



            this.lastBackPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else {


            //super.onBackPressed(); for exit

            //INTENT HERE TO YOUR SECOND ACTIVITY like below

             Intent intent=new Intent(A.this,B.class);
              startActivirty(intent);
        }

}
```

> Create a global variable

```
private long lastBackPressTime = 0;
```

Hope this will help you,Let me know..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override `onBackPressed()` if all you're going to do is call `startActivity()` and `finish()` in the current activity. The Android backstack will handle both of those for you. Moreover, in your `UserProfile.java` you are passing data to previous activity. For this, you should use `startActvityForResult()` in the `Comments` activity (i.e the previous activity) instead of `startActivity()`.

To learn more about `startActvityForResult()` visit: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html