# How to pass data between activities with startActivityForResult?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, startactivityforresult

I have three Activities A, B and C. The normal flow is **A --> B --> C --> A**

In activity A, I show a list of objects with recyclerView and if I select one of these items I go to activity B and I can modify these parameters.

In activity B there are three fragments where I can modify these parameters and when I confirm these changes in the third fragment I go to activity C and I can show these object with the parameters changed.

When I confirm the changes in activity B and go to activity C, the activity B is finished and start activity C.

My question is that i want to pass an object with the parameters changed from activity C to activity A.
A --> B -->**C --> A**

How can i do this with startActivityForResult ?

Comment: maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data from 2nd activity to 1st activity when pressed back? - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292398/how-to-pass-data-from-2nd-activity-to-1st-activity-when-pressed-back-android)

Comment: I want to know how to pass data between 3 activities no 2.