# Passing Value From View Class to Activity Class?

Tags: android

I have this mini-game and two activities. I used an intent to order my app to go from activity 1 (Just a menu screen) to activity 2. **However**, I want to return the game score from activity 2 back to activity 1 when the gameIsOver, but my second activity reads:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new DrawView (this));

}
```

}

So my activity is really run in the DrawView class which extends the View class. How may I return something back to activity 1 from a **View** Class?

Comment: `startActivityForResult`

Comment: please read about `interface`. That is one way to call activity method (in your issue ) without passing instance

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh `DrawView` extends from `View`, `startActivity` not working for view.

Comment: This link might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292398/how-to-pass-data-from-2nd-activity-to-1st-activity-when-pressed-back-android

Comment: @ShayanPourvatan OP said `However, I want to return the game score from activity 2 back to activity 1` though you are also right about callback mechanism between view and activity,  nice work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data from 2nd activity to 1st activity when pressed back? - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292398/how-to-pass-data-from-2nd-activity-to-1st-activity-when-pressed-back-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two things needed here:

**first - Your custom view need to report it's score to the hosting Activity2**

in order to achieve that make an interface called e.g.

```
public interface OnResult {
    void onResult(int result);
}
```

make your Activity2 implement `OnResult`, and let your custom DrawView class have a field `OnResult resultCallback;` , and let the activity put itself as this field.
e.g.

@Override

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DrawView view = new DrawView (this); // "this" here as a Context object
    view.setResultCallback(this); // "this" here as the OnResult listener object
    setContentView(view);
}
```

and than, from your custom view when there is a result call your resultCallback.onResult() (that is, call the activity)

read more about callback mechanism via interfaces [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3398416/3339597)

**second - in your activity2 pass the answer back to activity 1**

first of all, when starting activity2 from activity1 don't just start it using `startActivity()`, but start it for a result using `startActivityForResult()`

and in your activity2 implementation of `onResult()` from the first step, return the result via an intent and finish the activity -

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("editTextValue", "value_here")
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);        
finish();
```

read more about passing return values from one activity to another [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292398/how-to-pass-data-from-2nd-activity-to-1st-activity-when-pressed-back-android) (via @Uma Sankar)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think this works but I never learned callbacks yet. Thanks for hitting me up with the callback mechanism link