# How to calculate the sum of number in radio button that user click and then display that sum in another layout?

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I want to make a quiz app that can calculate the sum of the number in radio button that user click. How to caluclate the sum and how can I display the result in another layout after user click the button to generate the result?

[Question page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7Z85.png) [Result page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7tT7.png)

Here is the code for question layout (activity_main.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/instruction_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/instruction" />

    // Question 1

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question1_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/question1" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/question1_radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question1_radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion1Clicked"
                android:text="1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question1_radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="2" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question1_radioButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion1Clicked"
                android:text="3" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question1_radioButton4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion1Clicked"
                android:text="4" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question1_radioButton5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion1Clicked"
                android:text="5" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question1_radioButton6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion1Clicked"
                android:text="6" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question1_radioButton7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion1Clicked"
            android:text="7" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RadioGroup>

// Question 2

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question2_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/question2" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/question2_radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question2_radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion2Clicked"
            android:text="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question2_radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion2Clicked"
            android:text="2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question2_radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion2Clicked"
            android:text="3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question2_radioButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion2Clicked"
            android:text="4" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question2_radioButton5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion2Clicked"
            android:text="5" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question2_radioButton6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion2Clicked"
            android:text="6" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question2_radioButton7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion2Clicked"
            android:text="7" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RadioGroup>

// Question 3

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question3_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/question3" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/question3_radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question3_radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion3Clicked"
            android:text="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question3_radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion3Clicked"
            android:text="2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question3_radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion3Clicked"
            android:text="3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question3_radioButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion3Clicked"
            android:text="4" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question3_radioButton5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion3Clicked"
            android:text="5" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question3_radioButton6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion3Clicked"
            android:text="6" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question3_radioButton7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion3Clicked"
            android:text="7" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RadioGroup>

// Question 4

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question4_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/question4" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/question4_radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question4_radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion4Clicked"
            android:text="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question4_radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion4Clicked"
            android:text="2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question4_radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion4Clicked"
            android:text="3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question4_radioButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion4Clicked"
            android:text="4" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question4_radioButton5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion4Clicked"
            android:text="5" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question4_radioButton6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion4Clicked"
            android:text="6" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question4_radioButton7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RadioGroup>

// Question 5

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question5_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/question5" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/question5_radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question5_radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion5Clicked"
            android:text="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question5_radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion5Clicked"
            android:text="2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question5_radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion5Clicked"
            android:text="3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question5_radioButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion5Clicked"
            android:text="4" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question5_radioButton5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion5Clicked"
            android:text="5" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question5_radioButton6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion5Clicked"
            android:text="6" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question5_radioButton7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonQuestion5Clicked"
            android:text="7" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/jana_keputusan_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Jana Keputusan" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code for the question activity (MainActivity.java):

```
package com.android.resilien.resilienminver;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public int score = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button generate_result_button = findViewById(R.id.jana_keputusan_button);
    generate_result_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent generate_result_intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
            startActivity(generate_result_intent);
        }
    });
}

// Question 1 Radio Button clicked
public void onRadioButtonQuestion1Clicked(View view) {
    // Is the button checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.question1_radioButton1:
            if(checked) {score = score + 1;}
            break;
        case R.id.question1_radioButton2:
            if(checked) {score = score + 2;}
            break;
        case R.id.question1_radioButton3:
            if(checked) {score = score + 3;}
            break;
        case R.id.question1_radioButton4:
            if(checked) {score = score + 4;}
            break;
        case R.id.question1_radioButton5:
            if(checked) {score = score + 5;}
            break;
        case R.id.question1_radioButton6:
            if(checked) {score = score + 6;}
            break;
        case R.id.question1_radioButton7:
            if(checked) {score = score + 7;}
            break;
    }
}

// Question 2 Radio Button clicked
public void onRadioButtonQuestion2Clicked(View view) {
    // Is the button checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.question2_radioButton1:
            if(checked) {score = score + 1;}
            break;
        case R.id.question2_radioButton2:
            if(checked) {score = score + 2;}
            break;
        case R.id.question2_radioButton3:
            if(checked) {score = score + 3;}
            break;
        case R.id.question2_radioButton4:
            if(checked) {score = score + 4;}
            break;
        case R.id.question2_radioButton5:
            if(checked) {score = score + 5;}
            break;
        case R.id.question2_radioButton6:
            if(checked) {score = score + 6;}
            break;
        case R.id.question2_radioButton7:
            if(checked) {score = score + 7;}
            break;
    }
}

// Question 3 Radio Button clicked
public void onRadioButtonQuestion3Clicked(View view) {
    // Is the button checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.question3_radioButton1:
            if(checked) {score = score + 1;}
            break;
        case R.id.question3_radioButton2:
            if(checked) {score = score + 2;}
            break;
        case R.id.question3_radioButton3:
            if(checked) {score = score + 3;}
            break;
        case R.id.question3_radioButton4:
            if(checked) {score = score + 4;}
            break;
        case R.id.question3_radioButton5:
            if(checked) {score = score + 5;}
            break;
        case R.id.question3_radioButton6:
            if(checked) {score = score + 6;}
            break;
        case R.id.question3_radioButton7:
            if(checked) {score = score + 7;}
            break;
    }
}

// Question 4 Radio Button clicked
public void onRadioButtonQuestion4Clicked(View view) {
    // Is the button checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.question4_radioButton1:
            if(checked) {score = score + 1;}
            break;
        case R.id.question4_radioButton2:
            if(checked) {score = score + 2;}
            break;
        case R.id.question4_radioButton3:
            if(checked) {score = score + 3;}
            break;
        case R.id.question4_radioButton4:
            if(checked) {score = score + 4;}
            break;
        case R.id.question4_radioButton5:
            if(checked) {score = score + 5;}
            break;
        case R.id.question4_radioButton6:
            if(checked) {score = score + 6;}
            break;
        case R.id.question4_radioButton7:
            if(checked) {score = score + 7;}
            break;
    }
}

// Question 5 Radio Button clicked
public void onRadioButtonQuestion5Clicked(View view) {
    // Is the button checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.question5_radioButton1:
            if(checked) {score = score + 1;}
            break;
        case R.id.question5_radioButton2:
            if(checked) {score = score + 2;}
            break;
        case R.id.question5_radioButton3:
            if(checked) {score = score + 3;}
            break;
        case R.id.question5_radioButton4:
            if(checked) {score = score + 4;}
            break;
        case R.id.question5_radioButton5:
            if(checked) {score = score + 5;}
            break;
        case R.id.question5_radioButton6:
            if(checked) {score = score + 6;}
            break;
        case R.id.question5_radioButton7:
            if(checked) {score = score + 7;}
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you mean how do you send the result to another layout after the user presses the radio button?

Comment: for displaying result in next `activity` layout. You can use `Intent`
refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292398/how-to-pass-data-from-2nd-activity-to-1st-activity-when-pressed-back-android

Answer (score 1):

First i would strongly recommend to sum up the click method for all `RadioButtons` to one single method, e.g. `onRadioAction`:

**The layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/instruction_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/instruction" />

    // Question 1

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question1_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/question1" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/question1_radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question1_radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
                android:text="1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question1_radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="2" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question1_radioButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
                android:text="3" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question1_radioButton4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
                android:text="4" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question1_radioButton5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
                android:text="5" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question1_radioButton6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
                android:text="6" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question1_radioButton7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="7" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RadioGroup>

// Question 2

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question2_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/question2" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/question2_radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question2_radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question2_radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question2_radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question2_radioButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="4" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question2_radioButton5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="5" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question2_radioButton6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="6" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question2_radioButton7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="7" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RadioGroup>

// Question 3

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question3_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/question3" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/question3_radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question3_radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question3_radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question3_radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question3_radioButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="4" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question3_radioButton5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="5" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question3_radioButton6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="6" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question3_radioButton7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="7" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RadioGroup>

// Question 4

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question4_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/question4" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/question4_radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question4_radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question4_radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question4_radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question4_radioButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="4" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question4_radioButton5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="5" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question4_radioButton6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="6" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question4_radioButton7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RadioGroup>

// Question 5

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question5_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/question5" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/question5_radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question5_radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question5_radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question5_radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question5_radioButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="4" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question5_radioButton5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="5" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question5_radioButton6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="6" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/question5_radioButton7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="radioButtonAction"
            android:text="7" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/jana_keputusan_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Jana Keputusan" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**The activity:**

```
package com.android.resilien.resilienminver;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public int score = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button generate_result_button = findViewById(R.id.jana_keputusan_button);
    generate_result_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent generate_result_intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
            startActivity(generate_result_intent);
        }
    });
}



public void radioButtonAction(View view) {
    // Is the button checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.question5_radioButton1:
            if(checked) {score = score + 1;}
            break;
        case R.id.question5_radioButton2:
            if(checked) {score = score + 2;}
            break;
        case R.id.question5_radioButton3:
            if(checked) {score = score + 3;}
            break;
        case R.id.question5_radioButton4:
            if(checked) {score = score + 4;}
            break;
        case R.id.question5_radioButton5:
            if(checked) {score = score + 5;}
            break;
        case R.id.question5_radioButton6:
            if(checked) {score = score + 6;}
            break;
        case R.id.question5_radioButton7:
            if(checked) {score = score + 7;}
            break;
    }
}
```

To extend your app i would also recommend, that you generate the layout for questions dynamically in your source code, not as hardcoded layout xml.

Finally to display the result e.g. add a `Button` to the bottom and set the following code to display a dialog with the achieved score. As alternative you can also start a new `Activity` and show it there via `Intent` and `Bundle`.

```
    private onClickedButtonResult(View v) {     
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        //set icon 
         .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        //set title
        .setTitle("Your score")
        //set message
        .setMessage("You achieved a score of " + String.valueOf(score) + "!")
        //set positive button
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
           //Call finish to close your app   
                finish();
            }
        })
        .show();
}
```

Alternative:
**Show score in another `Activity`**
Create an `Intent` for the other `Activity` and save the value of score in the intent:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button generate_result_button = findViewById(R.id.jana_keputusan_button);
    generate_result_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent generate_result_intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
         Bundle extras = generate_result_intent.getExtras();
         extras.putExtra("SCORE", score);  
         startActivity(generate_result_intent);
       }
    });
```

}

And in your other `Activity` you can read the passed value of score and show it to the user:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_other);

    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    if (i.hasExtra("SCORE")) {
       int score = mIntent.getIntExtra("SCORE", 0);
       // Do something to display the score
    }
}
```

Finally, be aware that the user can increase his own score by clicking multiple times on a `RadioButton`. That should be addressed in your application logic, because the scoring would be invalid.

Comment: `putExtra` is a Method of `Intent` documented in the attached link. Can you please post your code, wehre you use `putExtra`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#putextra_16

Answer (score 0):

To get text from `RadioButton` I offer you to use:

```
int indexOfButton = radioGroup.indexOfChild(findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
String scoreS = (indexOfButton > -1)? ((RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(indexOfButton)).getText().toString() : "";
score += Integer.parseInt(scoreS);
```

This methods is getting checked `RadioButton` id and by it finds index in that group. By the index you can get `RadioButton` text.

To show the score in other activity you can send data throw `Intent` extras. Like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("result", score);
startActivity(intent);
```

On `ResultActivity.class` you can get score from extras like this:

```
Integer result = 0;
Intent i = getIntent();
if (i.hasExtra("result")) {
    result = i.getIntExtra("result");
}
```

Then you can display it in `TextView` or in other possible ways.

*If you don't understand something, feel free to ask.

I hope it helps you...*

Comment: how to display the result as TextView?
final TextView result_TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_text);
        int score = 0;
        Intent result_intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = result_intent.getExtras();
        if (result_intent.hasExtra("result")) {
            score = result_intent.getIntExtra("score", 0);
            result_TextView.setText("Skor: "+ score);
        }

Comment: It looks like everything is pretty good. Except don't define `TextView` as `final`. It says that object is final and you would not be able to change his value later. It calls *blanck final* because you creating it empty. And I think you don't need to create `Bundle` object if you not using it.

Comment: **final** TextView result_TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_text); is totally fine. `final` works here as immutable reference. That means, that a reference to the `TextView` score_text is immutable, but the `TextView` itself can be modified. Its rather a _bad_ practice to _not_ use `final` here, because this reference shouldn't be changed later. This brings advantages like null-safety, reducing side-effects etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to another activity and display result by INTENT. You can pass your score to another activity by using putExtra.

MainActivity:

```
okAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {   
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);   
        intent.putExtra("Score", score);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Another Activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
if(bundle != null){
   int score = bundle.getInt("Score");
   restltText.setText("Your score is: "+ score);
}
```