# I want to take the data and close the current layout on the click on the item of recyclerview

Tags: java, android

I'm stuck by a problem and I don't know how too resolve it.
I want to click on my item in my recycler view, and at this click the layout with the recylcer view will be closed, and my mainActivity will be refresh with the data of the item who i have click on.

Comment: I think you re-pasted the Activity file in the adapter part of your question. Please update the same.

Comment: My bad thank you

Comment: So you want to pass back the data from a specific RecyclerView item back to the MainActivity. Did I understand that right?

Comment: @SujalKumar Yes, that it.

Comment: I think this should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/14292451/9520315

Comment: I have tried this, but the setResult() and the finish() make an error like "Non-static method 'setResult(int, android.content.Intent)' cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: I'm beginner in computer programming, si I can have make a stupid mistake I don't know.

Comment: Can you update the code in the question with what you just tried?

Comment: I have updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 hours in the sauce I have resolve that and I'm very happy.
The problem with the setResult() and the finish() but if you apply this code

```
((StructureEnFeuActivity)context).setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
((StructureEnFeuActivity)context).finish();
```

You will not have the probleme with "static".
So I'm happy.
And thank you for all.

Answer (score 0):

you start new activity to get Data but here you start a normal intent you need to start Activity For Result like

```
startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
```

or new Way

```
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> result = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
        if(result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK){
            String data =  result.getData().getStringExtra("Data");
            // here your data come from next Activity
        }
    }
});
```

then call result by

```
 result.launch(Intent);
```

and in other Activity activity

you need to call

```
setResult(RESULT_OK,Intent);
    finish();
```

this intent hold your data and will return to previous activity with it

Comment: Thank you for your reply but that doesn't work because the setResult() and the finish() makes error

Comment: you donot do that  holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("editTextValue", "value_here")
            StructureEnFeuActivity.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            StructureEnFeuActivity.finish();

        }
    });
you need to use interface fire when any item click and pass any data u want to activity which hold recyclerView and in method you overrided  you will call finish() and set data

Comment: I have updated it with that and I have always the same problem

Comment: of course you have a problem , this implementation i see it for first time ,a don't make sure it work fine, how to call setResult and finish from adapter , as i said you need to use interface as callback fire when any item pressed , so you need to replace Activity object from adapter to an Interface class which will be fire an other side you will implement this class in StructureEnFeuActivity class and override its method inside this method do this work setResult and finish

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how to resolve it